# how to deal with a Server close TCP

Tags: c, unix, tcp, client-server

Right now I've got a simple TCP server/client. I have it set up so that whenever a client connects it gets forked() and the connection itself is put into an infinite loop so that the connection stays open. The server is receiving information from the client, I have a check to make sure that the number of bytes received is > 0. That has been working well so far in determining if the client has disconnected. But if the server disconnects the client will shut down too but no errno gets set. How can I check to make sure the server is still connected?

Comment: Your Q is not very clear. Do you want to make sure that the server stays connected while transmitting the information to the client?

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if the remote end of a TCP connection has closed?

Comment: Yes I'd like to know what to do client side if the server randomly disconnects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the other end disconnects, the socket will become readable (a read on socket will not block) and the `read()` will return `0`.  That's the usual way disconnection is detected (it sounds like you're doing this on the server side already).

If you're blocked in a `write()` or try to `write` on a socket closed by the other end, your process will recieve a `SIGPIPE` signal and `write` will return `-1` with `errno` set to `EPIPE`.

The default action for `SIGPIPE` is to terminate the process, so if you haven't changed that, your client will just die when it tries to write to a server that's gone away.

Comment: Just before I read this answer I remembered to run it through gdb and saw it was sigpipe. I'll give you credit where credit is due though. Thanks!